# Kubernetes through VirtualBox: Pods can't access internet services

Tags: networking, kubernetes, proxy, dns, firewall

**Solution**

The Problem disappeared after I moved to a proper development server. Apparently the Kubernetes cluster does not properly run with bridged AirPort network environments in Virutalbox.

---

### **[Moved it to ServerFault because off topic.](https://serverfault.com/questions/1038655/kubernetes-pods-cant-access-internet-services)**

---

I've setup a deployment and a service and I am exposing it via NodePort but my Pods somehow cant access the internet. The worker node which runs the pod however has an internet connection. I tested this by exec into the running pod and curl a webpage.

**Pods**

```
root@master:/home/user# kubectl get pods
NAME                               READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
my-website-6d8f7c7bfb-sdtrh        1/1     Running     1          6d1h
```

**Curl from Host**

```
root@master:/home/user# curl https://wikipedia.org
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://www.wikipedia.org/">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

**Exec Pod - Curl**

```
root@master:/home/user# kubectl exec -it my-website-6d8f7c7bfb-sdtrh /bin/bash
root@my-website-6d8f7c7bfb-sdtrh:/sbin# curl https://wikipedia.org
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: wikipedia.org
```

Anyone an idea what that could be? I'm fairly new to DevOps, so I don't know quite as much about all of that yet.

**EDIT for Howard_Roark**

1. I've checked and yes the two `/etc/resolv.conf`'s differ.

**On worker node**

```
root@worker:~# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Generated by NetworkManager
search fritz.box
nameserver 192.168.178.1
```

**Inside Pod**

```
/ # cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 10.96.0.10
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local fritz.box
options ndots:5
```

2. From the node itself I can get out to another name server, but not from the pod.

```
root@worker:~# nslookup wikipedia.org 8.8.8.8
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   wikipedia.org
Address: 91.198.174.192
Name:   wikipedia.org
Address: 2620:0:862:ed1a::1


root@worker:~# nslookup wikipedia.org 1.1.1.1
Server:     1.1.1.1
Address:    1.1.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   wikipedia.org
Address: 91.198.174.192
Name:   wikipedia.org
Address: 2620:0:862:ed1a::1
```

3. Is presumable gonna fail too hence 2. But I'll test it now.

Comment: The fact you tagged your question with `proxy` is almost a dead giveaway -- presumably your host has some kind of proxy through which it connects to the outside world? If there is an environment variable `https_proxy` set in your environment, then curl would use it without you having to explicitly say `--proxy` on the command line. Running curl in verbose mode `curl -v https://wikipedia.org` will show the handshake with a proxy, if any. Be aware that if you are using a proxy, you'll need to provide its MITM CA to those Pods, also

Comment: It looks like you are having dns resolution issues.  If you cat your `/etc/resolv.conf` on your node where your curl request works and compare it to your `/etc/resolv.conf` in your container where your curl request fails, are they the same?

Answer (score 2):

To troubleshoot the `could not resolve host` error you are seeing in your Pod but not on your Node, I would:

1. `cat /etc/resolv.conf` in my pod to see if it differs from the `/etc/resolv.conf` on the node
2. I would try looking up wikipedia.org by passing in a specific nameserver within the container (install `nslookup` if needed in your running container):

```
nslookup wikipedia.org 8.8.8.8
Server:  dns.google
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    wikipedia.org
Addresses:  2620:0:861:ed1a::1
         208.80.154.224
```

3. I would try running my pod spec with a specific [dnsConfig](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-dns-config) that includes my nameserver of choice

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: dns-example
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test
      image: nginx
  dnsPolicy: "None"
  dnsConfig:
    nameservers:
      - 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I edited my question with the results.

Comment: is there any way to solve it centrally instead of adding dnsConfig in every pod?

Comment: Ya you should set the nameservers you need via DHCP options.  Your containers would then use those of your host in /etc/resolv.conf.  If you went the route of my answer though (which weirdly I don't remember writing), you could do something fancy with a mutating webhook that triggers and adds dns resolvers to your specs whenever a pod spec is submitted